# scrollToIndex out of range: item length 0 but minimum is 1

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

My horizontal `FlatList` works fine with dummy data but when i try to pass data from backend to my `FlatList` it returns the error `scrollToIndex out of range: requested index -1 but minimum is 0`.

Data is passed correctly in vertical `FlatList` but when i try with the horizontal one, it gives this error.

What do you think is wrong with my horizontal `FlatList` code?

```jsx
useEffect(() => {
    const getIndex = (placeholder = 0) => {
        const index = places.findIndex(place => place.id === selectedPlaceId);
        if (index === -1) return placeholder;
        return index;
    };

    const index = getIndex();

    flatlist.current.scrollToIndex({index});

    const selectedPlace = places[index];
    const region = {
        latitude: selectedPlace.coordinate.latitude,
        longitude: selectedPlace.coordinate.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: 0.8,
        longitudeDelta: 0.8
    }

    map.current.animateToRegion(region);

}, [selectedPlaceId])


return (
    <FlatList
         ref={flatlist}
         data={trips}
         renderItem={({ item }) => <PostCarouselItem post={item} />}
         horizontal
         showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
         snapToInterval={width - 70}
         snapToAlignment={"center"}
         decelerationRate={"fast"}
         viewabilityConfig={viewConfig.current}
         onViewableItemsChanged={onViewChanged.current}
         style={{ bottom: 10, left: 0, right: 0, position: "absolute", }}
         contentContainerStyle={{ marginHorizontal: cardWidth }}
         ListFooterComponent={<View style={{marginRight: (cardWidth * 2)}}/>}
    />
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) [returns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#return_value) `-1` if it does not find an element that matches the condition.

You need to check your condition and add validation for index value.

As example:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const getIndex = (placeholder = 0) => {
        const index = places.findIndex(place => place.id === selectedPlaceId);
        if (index === -1) return placeholder;
        return index;
    };

    const index = getIndex();

    if (index < trips.length) {
        flatlist.current.scrollToIndex({index});
    }

    const selectedPlace = places[index];
    const region = {
        latitude: selectedPlace.coordinate.latitude,
        longitude: selectedPlace.coordinate.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: 0.8,
        longitudeDelta: 0.8
    }

    map.current.animateToRegion(region);

}, [places, selectedPlaceId, trips])
```

Comment: thanks, it shows same error but item length 0, minimum is 1, what am i missing here?

Comment: Please add the full component code and the detailed output of the current error to your question

Comment: Can you please have a look now thanks -

Comment: How you fill your `trips` variable? I have now added additional check before make `scrollToIndex`

Comment: thanks for the edit, it seems working fine now. For `trips` I am using `const [trips, setTrips] = useState([]);`